# Is there any way to color google sheet cells using python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

```
if data:
    print("Redirected")
    cellNum = wks.acell(f'A{countt}')  
    # I want to color this cell (the cell number is stored in cellNum (<Cell R2C1>))
else:
    print("Not")
```

I want to color the cell for which my condition is true.

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set a background color to a cell.
- From your showing script, you want to achieve this using gspread for python.
- You have already been able to get and put values to Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
if data:
    print("Redirected")
    cellNum = wks.acell(f"A{countt}")

    wks.format(cellNum.address, {"backgroundColor": {"red": 1, "green": 0, "blue": 0}}) # <--- Added

else:
    print("Not")
```

- When this script is run, the background color of cell of `cellNum` is changed to red.
- In this case, the values of RGB are 0 to 1. So, please divide the value of RGB by 255. So, the red color is `{"red": 1, "green": 0, "blue": 0}`. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [format(ranges, format)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=background#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.format)
- [Color](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#Color)

Comment: yeah now its perfectly working thanks

Comment: @Alfaz Sozib Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.